# Time complexity of divide and conquer relation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I was trying two calculate the time complexity of  below function.
I tried two different methods

1) Since nearly every time there will be two recursive calls .
   we can write the recurrence relation as `T(n)=2T(n/2)+c`.
   which gives us `O(logn)`.

2)But we can say also say that total number of recursive calls will be
   equal to n which gives us time complexity as `O(n)`.
   since every time number is getting half but there are two recursive calls.

which one is correct ?

I saw second method from herehttps://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-calculate-powxn/

see the time complexity of method 1 in above link

Note->I know we can store the result of power(x,n/2) .

```
/* Function to calculate x raised to the power n */

int power(int x, unsigned int n) 
{ 
    if (n == 0) 
        return 1; 
    else if (n%2 == 0) 
        return power(x, n/2)*power(x, n/2); 
    else
        return x*power(x, n/2)*power(x, n/2); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Since nearly every time there will be two recursive calls .
>      we can write the recurrence relation as `T(n)=2T(n/2)+c`.
>      which gives us `O(logn)`.

You have made a mistake here somehow. *T*(*n*) = 2‍*T*(*n*/2) + *c* does *not* give *O*(log *n*); rather, it gives *O*(*n*). (This falls under Case 1 at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms).)

> 2)But we can say also say that total number of recursive calls will be
>      equal to n which gives us time complexity as `O(n)`.
>      since every time number is getting half but there are two recursive calls.

This is correct.

Comment: @kjsir121 - There's no proof of master method on wiki, probalby [this doc](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjltOjCkq3gAhUzwsQBHfpaBf0QFjAAegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.cornell.edu%2Fcourses%2Fcs3110%2F2012sp%2Flectures%2Flec20-master%2Fmm-proof.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0rvy4f3C0U3sTJ_1TyqqGC) could be useful if you are interested in proof.

Answer (score 0):

So T(n)=2T(n/2)+c 
This actually comes out to be O(n) itself.

Here is the formal proof to that .
T(n)=2T(n/2^1 )+c(2^0)

Breaking it further

T(n)=2(2T(n/2^2 )+c)+c(2^0 )

Simplifying this :

T(n)=2^2 T(n/2^2 )+c(2^0 )+c(2^1 )

If you break it further which you can try you will get an expression like this

T(n)=2^3 T(n/2^3 )+c(2^0 )+c(2^1 )+c(2^2)

Now the key is how far can you break it , that should be to the point when 2^something becomes equals to n so that n/n=1 and T(1) is constant.

That something can easily be calculate as log(n)base(2).

So by inspection you can predict that your final expression would look like this,

T(n)=2^log(n) T(n/2^log(n))+c(2^0)+c(2^1)+........+2^(log(n)-1)

```
=n T(1)+c(2^0+2^1+2^2+.......2^(log(n)-1))

=n T(1)+c(n-1)
```

Thus,

T(n)= (T(1)+c)n-c which is o(n).